# Traveling from Brussel to Spa-Francorchamps with overnight stay

Tags: trains, buses, belgium, brussels, formula-one

What is a cheap and easy way to travel by train and/or bus from central Brussel to circuit de Spa-Francorchamps?
It has to include a stop for an overnight stay along the way, within 60 min from Spa-Francorchamps!

Is there a map of the bus stops along the way, to make it easier to choose a place for the overnigth stay?
Right now I'm looking at Verviers or maybe Embourg, Chaudfontaine if it has a bus stop going to Spa-Francorchamps?

Comment: Where in Brussels would you depart from? Or just general "Brussel"?

Comment: Just some where downtown, like Brussels-Midi/Zuid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the website from the country's railway company [(NMBS in dutch, SNCB in English/french)](https://www.belgiantrain.be/en/).

In destination you can fill in "Malmedy - Bevercé, Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps" (or fill in spa fran.. and it should give you suggestions)

You get alot of traveltime options ranging from 2 hours 17 minutes till 2 hours 37 minutes.

Depending on the day/time you get different options.

Regarding your stay in Verviers, it looks like a good option because the bus, departing from the train station in Verviers takes about 35 minutes.

Traintickets you can buy at the trainstation.
Bustickets you can buy in the bus, by text or a machine looking like this: [image: busticket selling machine]

Comment: If want to broaden my answer more when the question is "more" clear.

Comment: Can I pay with VISA or Mastercard on the bus?

Comment: Paying on the bus is only possible with cash. Paying on the bus also *should* be more expensive then buying the ticket at the machine.
At the machine you can use Visa and Mastercard (looking at the picture of the vending machine)